# ASP.NET 4 downloaded files in CHROME IOS corrupted

Tags: asp.net

the problem occurs only with chrome/IOS. downloading on safari/ios, chrome/windows, chrome/mac works fine. all downloaded files from our site are corrupted(zip and pdf) when using chrome/ios. Also Chrome and ios is on latest version. How can we fix it?

```
 private static HttpResponse NewHttpResponse_OpenFile(string fileName)
    {
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

        System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser;
        if (browser.Browser.Equals("IE") || browser.Browser.Equals("InternetExplorer"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)) + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName));
        }
        else
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Q: So what exactly do you mean by "corrupted"?  Q: Have you compared the file sizes (in bytes)?  Q: The problem occurs *ONLY* with a Chrome browser, and *ONLY* on an iOS handset?  For example, downloading on Safari/iOS works, and downloading on Chrome/Windows also works?  Please provide as much additional info as you can.

Comment: @paulsm4 Yes the problem occurs only with chrome/IOS. downloading on safari/ios, chrome/windows, chrome/mac works fine. We also tried installing acrobat reader(pdf reader) but no luck. all downloaded files from our site are corrupted(zip and pdf) when using chrome/ios.

Comment: You absolutely need to try to determine what exactly is "corrupt".  You can't "fix it" until you *understand* it. Is the file truncated (fewer bytes)? Have you checked the byte count? Does Chrome/iOS successfully download and display *OTHER* .pdfs from other sites?  As a workaround, perhaps you can tell your users the current version of Chrome is unsupported on iOS.